# Implementing Moreland-balanced color maps in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, color

I'm trying to implement improved color maps to increase the data density in my plots and graphics (as described in *Envisioning Information* by Edward Tufte) and after much searching, found what I believe to be a well-optimized method for generating color maps for displaying scientific information, described by [Kenneth Moreland in this paper](https://www.kennethmoreland.com/color-maps/ColorMapsExpanded.pdf).  It wasn't too difficult to implement a simplified version of his most important color map (red-white-blue, great for displaying relative temperature profiles) simply by using the 33 RGB coordinates he tabulates in the paper, and that's what I've shown here:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotsset{
    % define the custom colormap
    colormap={temp colormap}{
    %   RGB Coordinates,     % Scalar   Band Number
        rgb255=(59, 76, 192),% 0.0        1
        rgb255=(68, 90, 204),% 0.03125    2
        rgb255=(77, 104, 215),%0.0625     3
        rgb255=(87, 117, 225),%0.09375    4
        rgb255=(98, 130, 234),%0.125      5
        rgb255=(108, 142, 241),%0.15625   6
        rgb255=(119, 154, 247),%0.1875    7
        rgb255=(130, 165, 251),%0.21875   8
        rgb255=(141, 176, 254),%0.25      9
        rgb255=(152, 185, 255),%0.28125   10
        rgb255=(163, 194, 255),%0.3125    11
        rgb255=(174, 201, 253),%0.34375   12
        rgb255=(184, 208, 249),%0.375     13
        rgb255=(194, 213, 244),%0.40625   14
        rgb255=(204, 217, 238),%0.4375    15
        rgb255=(213, 219, 230),%0.46875   16
        rgb255=(221, 221, 221),%0.5       17
        rgb255=(229, 216, 209),%0.53125   18
        rgb255=(236, 211, 197),%0.5625    19
        rgb255=(241, 204, 185),%0.59375   20
        rgb255=(245, 196, 173),%0.625     21
        rgb255=(247, 187, 160),%0.65625   22
        rgb255=(247, 177, 148),%0.6875    23
        rgb255=(247, 166, 135),%0.71875   24
        rgb255=(244, 154, 123),%0.75      25
        rgb255=(241, 141, 111),%0.78125   26
        rgb255=(236, 127, 99),%0.8125     27
        rgb255=(229, 112, 88),%0.84375    28
        rgb255=(222, 96, 77),%0.875       29
        rgb255=(213, 80, 66),%0.90625     30
        rgb255=(203, 62, 56),%0.9375      31
        rgb255=(192, 40, 47),%0.96875     32
        rgb255=(180, 4, 38),%1.0          33
    },
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
        hide axis,
        scale only axis,
        height=0pt,
        width=0pt,
        colormap name=temp colormap,
        colorbar sampled,
        colormap access=piecewise const, % add this
        colorbar horizontal,
        point meta min=1,
        point meta max=33,
        colorbar style={
            xlabel={Relative Temperature},
            samples=33,
            height=0.5cm,
            width=10cm,
            xtick style={
                color=black}
            },
    ]
        \addplot [draw=none] coordinates {(0,0)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Which gives the following output:

[image: Output of Colormaps.tex]

However, a more general solution would be preferable.  I see two ways to approach such an improvement:

1. It would be better if one could specify the number of gradations, so that very dense data sets could use more than the 33 level provided.  I believe it should be possible to write an interpolation function to extend the 33 data points into an arbitrary number, but am unsure how to approach this, particularly since the RGB values in question change in a non-linear way.
2. It would be nice if one could use arbitrary color endpoints for the "red" and "blue" ends of the colormap.  This would require implementing the MSH color space transformation and algorithm Moreland describes in the paper I've linked.  This is very far beyond me, to the point where I can't even post a minimal working example. However, since LaTeX is Turing-complete, it should in theory be possible.

To be clear, I am mostly interested in the simpler non-linear interpolation approach requested in (1) which would fully meet my needs for the moment, but I thought I would post option (2) as an interesting, perhaps even fun, challenge for those who might also be interested in using optimal color spaces, and are considerably more skilled than I.  An implementation in LaTeX of the MSH transformation and color space would make it easy for any new color mappings to simultaneously:

- yield images that are aesthetically pleasing.
- have a maximal perceptual resolution.
- minimize interference with the shading of 3D surfaces.
- be insensitive to vision deficiencies.
- have a color order that is intuitively the same for all people.
- have a perceptual interpolation that matches the underlying scalars of the map.

Anyone who could write the code that permits all that would be a hero to many scientists who use color to display quantitative information on a regular basis!